# how to create a function for the following requirement

Tags: python-3.x

I created a function that returns the absolute value of a provided single argument and prints a statement "Not possible" if the argument provided is not a number. To solve the task, I used the type() function in the body of distance_from_zero().

```
def distance_from_zero(abs(x)):
    if x is type(int):
        return 
    else:
        print("not possible")
```

I was expecting it to give me the output if I put any integer in-place of 'x' but once I run the cell it only gives me the output as 'Not possible'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!!
When posting your follow up questions, note you can format your code so it is not changed to inline text. Either use the GUI "Format" button, or enclose your code in triple-backtip-quotes ( \`\`\`)

Answer (score 2):

`type()` is a built-in function used to get the type of an object. You're attempting to use it incorrectly. Instead, you should use `isinstance()` to check if `x` is of type `int`. You need to properly handle the case when `x` is an integer. Currently, your function does not return any value when `x` is an integer. Try like this:

```
def distance_from_zero(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return abs(x)
    else:
        print("Not possible")
```

Also, if you want to check if it's number and not just integer, you can do it like this:

```
if isinstance(x, (int, float, complex)):
```